# JavaScript from chrome console to standalone node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have made a script that works if I input it in Google Chrome developer console.
I want it to be a executable file I open and want it to log everything in it in a standalone node.js console window. And also so it runs the script on the specific website.

I have no clue on how to do that.
It's not my website.

Answer (score -1):

You can use some headless browser in your node server, and to do that, there are some libraries, Here I'm sharing a link to one of that (puppeteer) and you can learn it from Youtube.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer